# How to predict harmful words using TensorFlow.js

Tags: javascript, prediction, cpu-word, tensorflow.js

Predict harmful words using TensorFlow.js, someone give a full example please....

I've search around a lot more, but there are example exist only for python, not for JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the toxicity model that can be used out of the box to predict if a word or a phrase is toxic or not. Here is the example from [docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/toxicity)

```js
const threshold = 0.9;
 
// Load the model. Users optionally pass in a threshold and an array of
// labels to include.
toxicity.load(threshold).then(model => {
  const sentences = ['you suck'];
 
  model.classify(sentences).then(predictions => {
    // `predictions` is an array of objects, one for each prediction head,
    // that contains the raw probabilities for each input along with the
    // final prediction in `match` (either `true` or `false`).
    // If neither prediction exceeds the threshold, `match` is `null`.
 
    console.log(predictions);
    /*
    prints:
    {
      "label": "identity_attack",
      "results": [{
        "probabilities": [0.9659664034843445, 0.03403361141681671],
        "match": false
      }]
    },
    {
      "label": "insult",
      "results": [{
        "probabilities": [0.08124706149101257, 0.9187529683113098],
        "match": true
      }]
    },
    ...
     */
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/toxicity"></script>
```

Comment: And please give me some example on simple word  prediction using TensorFlow Js

Comment: What do you mean ? It is easier to help if you show what you have done